# Get sorted value from an array in php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress, sorting

i used kirki drag and drop wordpress plugin for my site  to create a sortable list when dragable is enabled.

i was able to create a setting that outputs this array, when i did var_dump for the settings here was what i got

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "Big Grid 1" [1]=> string(10) "Big Grid 2" [2]=> string(10) "Big Grid 3" }
```

when in var_dump it sorts correctly when i drag and drop any element, they take there place as sorted in the var_dump array, to me the array given is completely useless till i set values for them .

so the question is how do i output them in php to get sorted just as they where in the array.

i tried switch case but its not working.

here is my code

```
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $value) {
switch ($key) {
    case 'Big grid 1' :
        // do something
        break ;
    case 'Big grid 2' :
        // do something
        break ;
    case 'Big grid 3' :
        // do something
        break ;
 }
 }
```

please i need help on this one.

hope my question was clear.

i am no PHP expert, thus a complex answer would be well appreciated.

Comment: that are values, not keys

Comment: switch ($value) in your case not  switch ($key) !

Answer (score 2):

not sure what you are trying to do with using `switch` statement and I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with that code you have,

but as I understand about your question, you just want to output the value of an array,

then you can do something like

```
$items = array("Big Grid 1","Big Grid 2","Big Grid 3");

$output = '';
foreach ($items as $item ) {
    $output .= $item .'<br/>';
}

echo $output; // or return $output if you need a return value
```

Comment: i want to output the value of the array as indexed in the array , like in order, the sortable does the order .

Comment: ```foreach``` handles that for you

Comment: or post your desired expected output to make it more clear of what you need

Comment: the default value from the array has , array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Big Grid 1" } , when i check visibility mode on in other sortable item they become visible , and the array changes to array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "Big Grid 1" [1]=> string(10) "Big Grid 2" [2]=> string(10) "Big Grid 3" } , if i drag and drop any item, they re-order in the array say array item two takes the place of array item one when i drag and drop, i just want a way to make the value maintain they index in the array (obviously when sorted ) . this is how best i can explain my problem. - https://snag.gy/chxVb3.jpg

Comment: ey , it worked m thanks bro i jess figured it out ... infact i didnt figure it out, i used it like dat ... tanks a million tyms